# requestSignatureFromDocument returnUrl not work

Tags: docusignapi

i add a 'returnUrl' in data array in

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument

but its not work. please help

```
$data = array (
"emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document",
"documents" => array( array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => $documentName)),
"recipients" => array( "signers" => array(
array( "email" => $email,
"name" => $recipientName,
"recipientId" => "1",
"tabs" => array(
"signHereTabs" => array(
 array( "xPosition" => "100",
"yPosition" => "100",
"documentId" => "1",
"pageNumber" => "1" )
))
))
),
 "status" => "sent",
 "returnUrl" => "http://www.google.com/",
 "authenticationMethod" => "None",
 "email" => $email,
"userName" => 'test',
"clientUserId" => 1
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `returnUrl` parameter is only used for Embedding functionality, so you can not use it with the Request Signature on Document API call.  It is used when you embed DocuSign into an app or website, and once the user is done sending a document, signing a document, or using the DocuSign Console, the `returnUrl` is used to redirect them to where you want.

Have a look at the Embedding API Walkthroughs if you want to use returnUrl:

[Embedded Sending](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSending)

[Embedded Signing](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning)

[Embedded DocuSign Console](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedDocuSign)

Comment: ok thanks. it work in embedding only.

i have one more question. how to Embed without $templateId ? like upload a pdf and embed? thanks

Comment: If you want to do embedded signing without a template, you just have to alter how you create the envelope.  Try using the Request Signature On Document API call and add the `clientUserId` property to your recipient.  Then after the envelope is created make the Embedded Signing API call...